# Gebrauch des Verbs "beischlafen"

Tags: verb-usage

Auf der Suche nach den Verben zum Thema „Präfix + *schlafen*“ bin ich über das Verb *beischlafen* gestolpert. Bis jetzt habe ich es nur als Nomen *der Beischlaf* gehört. Ich habe nachgelesen, dass dieses Verb selten im Sprachgebrauch vorkommt und veraltet ist. Mich würde dennoch interessieren, wie man *beischlafen* im Satz benutzt (Präsens/Perfekt)? Ich habe folgendes Beispiel im Netz gefunden (woraus ich entnehme, dass das Verb das Objekt im Dativ verlangt):

> Wer seinem Kinde oder einem anderen seiner Nachkommen beischläft, wird
> mit Zuchthaus von zwei bis zu acht Jahren bestraft.
> (https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/beischlafen)

Wären diese Sätze etwa richtig?

¿? Er schläft ihr bei.

¿? Sie hat ihm beigeschlafen.

¿? Sie haben beigeschlafen.

Könntet Ihr mir bitte mithilfe einfacher Satzbeispiele den Gebrauch von diesem Verb illustrieren?

Comment: Beim letzten Satz fehlt mir das Objekt, also etwa „Sie haben *einander* beigeschlafen.“

Comment: https://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/beischlafen.htm

Comment: @RHa. Na so ein Quatsch, im ersten Absatz steht: „Zum besseren Verständnis stehen unzählige Beispiele für das Verb beischlafen zur Verfügung.“ Wenn man dann auf den Link klickt, sind gar keine Beispielsätze eingetragen. Ich hatte schonmal Probleme mit der Seite, weil dort für eine bestimmte Art von Verben – ich weiß nicht mehr welche – Verbformen angegeben waren, die ein Computer falsch aus ähnlichen Verben abgeleitet hatte (so die Antwort auf meine Meldung beim Seitenbetreiber). Seitdem weiß ich: auch die Seite kann man als verlässliche Quelle vergessen.

Comment: Man benutzt dieses Verb gar nicht. Es ist ein sehr gutes Beispiel für ein veraltetes Wort, da es tatsächlich allenfalls noch verwendet wird, wenn man einem gekünstelten oder historierenden Stil erzeugen will. Interessant wäre, wann das Verb aus der Mode gekommen ist: schon Anfang des 20 Jhd. oder erst mit der sexuellen Revolution?

Comment: @Björn Friedrich so wie die Frage formuliert ist, ist der Fragesteller an den Konjugationsformen interessiert, und die sind auf der Seite sehr wohl aufgelistet. Andernfalls sollte die Frage präziser formuliert werden.

Comment: Die Frage sieht wie eine Bitte um Korrekturlesen aus, denn Wiktionary hat zwei Beispielsätze und alle nötigen Informationen (Perfekt mit *haben*, Dativobjekt).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ja, richtig, das Wort wird heutzutage praktisch nicht mehr benutzt, und wenn doch, dann meist mit ironischem Anklang. In von Tabuisierung der Sexualität geprägten Zeiten war es eine gute Möglichkeit, den Akt auf einem hohen Sprachniveau zu benennen.

Im deutschen Strafgesetzbuch §173 ist aktuell von "den Beischlaf vollziehen" die Rede. Auch diese Formulierung wirkt heute altmodisch, aber schwer mit etwas Besserem zu ersetzen. Sie macht noch etwas prägnanter und für heutige Ohren verständlicher klar, dass es nicht nur um ein Nebeneinanderliegen geht.

Der Gebrauch des Verbs ist nicht weiter schwierig, es steht mit einem Dativobjekt (jemandem beischlafen), deine Beispiele sind also alle korrekt. Wenn man im dritten Beispiel ausdrücken möchte, dass zwei Menschen miteinander geschlafen haben, hört sich für mich besser an:

> Sie haben einander beigeschlafen.

Weitere Beispiele:

> In dieser Nacht schlief Luise Adalbert bei.
> In jener Nacht schlief Adalbert Luise bei.
> Vor ihrer Hochzeitsnacht hatte Adalbert noch keiner Frau beigeschlafen.

Comment: Es gibt auch den Ausdruck "beiwohnen": "Wir waren miteinander nicht befreundet, doch haben wir einander beigewohnt." - https://www.deutschelyrik.de/liebeslied-aus-einerschlechten-zeit.html

Answer (score 3):

Das [**d**igitale **W**örterbuch der **d**eutschen **S**prache](https://www.dwds.de/wb/beischlafen#gb-1) liefert folgende Beispiele:

> Wo vergewaltigt oder sonstwie beigeschlafen wird, suhlt die Regie in drastischem Realismus. (Die Welt, 06.11.1999)

> Auf den Miniaturen tummeln sich Männchen und Weibchen beischlafend und schaumbadend, schmusend und fensterscheibenputzend. (Die Zeit, 04.12.2000, Nr. 49)

Ist mir als Verb nie zu Lebzeiten untergekommen. Ich frag mich grad, inwieweit man das bis heute gewohnte "*schlafe bei*" als naher Verwandter von "*beischlafen*" sehen kann ("*ich schlafe bei ihr*" ist in erster Linie Präposition/Ortsangabe, aber sehr nahe an "*ich schlafe ihr bei*" dran, auch vom Sinn her).